# how to print to network thermal printer using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, thermal-printer, qprinter

I want to print some data from Database to ethernet connected printer. I can print to USB Thermal printer but i don't know show to connect to Networked printer.

Qt Creator 5.9.1 on Windows 7.

```cpp
QFont bFont = QApplication::
QFont sFont = QApplication::
QFontMetrics fm(sFont);
bFont.setBold(true);
bFont.setPixelSize(10);
sFont.setPointSize(8);
sFont.setPixelSize(9);
Printer.setPrinterName(PrinterName);
Printer.setPaperSize(QSizeF(57,100), QPrinter::Millimeter);
QPainter p(&Printer);
if(Printer.printerState() == QPrinter::Error)
  {
     emit ShowMessageBox("There is a Problem With Printer: ");
  }
   else
  {

    p.drawText(QRectF(0,Line,Printer.width(),13),Qt::AlignCenter, "***ORDER RECEIPT***" );
  }
```

I want to know who can i print this through network connected Thermal printer as there is no device name in Device Panel on IP address i have.

Comment: In Windows, you print at the HDC level, not at a link layer level.